# valueState of Switch

Tags: sapui5

I would like have a way to show to user the error contextualized in a **Switch** (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Switch.html) in the same way as I do with Input (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/1.36.7/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputBase.html) by `valueState` and `valueStateText` properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documantation it is not intented to provide such a feature. 
Nevertheless, as I remember providing valueState and valueStateText activates specific css classes, and this can also be done for the switch control.

e.g. in the event handler of the change event: you can addStyleClass or removeStyleClass.

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for only works out of the box for controls that extend [sap.m.InputBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputBase.html) which in turn inherits from [sap.ui.core.Control](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html). However, [sap.m.Switch](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Switch.html) only extends [sap.ui.core.Control](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html). That's why [sap.m.Switch](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Switch.html) does not support what you want out of the box.

You could implement your own custom Switch control that extends [sap.m.InputBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputBase.html) to get what you want (recommended). Or you could write some JavaScript or CSS hacks to achieve what you want with the sap.m.Switch (not recommended).